# Togetherness sucks - What am I?

Tags: word, wordplay

> People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.
>   I've had an impact on many products and artists.
>   It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.
>   I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.
>   Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

What am I?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Rainbow

People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.

> The rainbow is more beautiful when all the colours are separated (if they were all together, it would just be white light)

I've had an impact on many products and artists.

> Skittles? Taste the rainbow! Also I'm sure many paintings contain rainbows.

It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.

> Some people are fully or partially colourblind

I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.

> Can mark the end of a storm, when the sun comes out and creates a rainbow

Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

> Many say there is a pot of gold at the end of the rainbow!

Comment: _"It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components"_ could also refer to the _answer_ carrying on beyond what we can see. But That would be _all people_ I suppose.

Comment: why is _the answer_  upset by that, though?

Comment: "I've had an impact on many products and artists" - if we interpret the answer as the full range of colours, then without it, artists would be restricted to shades of grey.

Comment: If we're talking about more than just visual artists, 'artists' could include singers. As Kermit the Frog once asked, "Why are there so many songs about rainbows/ and what's on the other side?"

Comment: Awesome. This is the right answer. Could you please explain how did you get to this answer?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal The last two lines made me think of the answer. Then I checked it against the lines above and it seemed to fit.

Answer (score 5):

are you

> Loneliness

People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.

> Lonliness is the opposite of unity, in a way

I've had an impact on many products and artists.

> Many artists tend to be loners

It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.

> most people don't see the value in spending time alone

I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.

> Being alone can be a rest at the end of difficult times

Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

> People don't want to be alone anymore, even though it's sometimes good for you to spend time by yourself.

Comment: Nice approach but not the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> Death

People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.

> Death takes away people from their loved ones

I've had an impact on many products and artists.

> Artists have made paintings on death

It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.

> Some people believe different theories of what happens when you die.

I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.

> When someone dies, it usually happens after intense pain, sickness, old age, being shot or wounded, or euthanasia.

Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

> People keep trying to find ways to resurrect people from the dead.

Comment: A totally different view. This isn't what I had in mind though :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a

> black hole

People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.

> The universe is full of beautiful nebulas, planets, and stars.  None of which keep all of their mass in precisely one place like I do.  Once you do that it's hard to show off.

I've had an impact on many products and artists.

> I've been featured in books, movies, planetariums, and Romulan warbird cloaking devices.

It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.

> It's hard to see past my event horizon.  My singularity is cloaked from sight.  But my secondary effects can be dazzling.  Can I interest you in my accretion disk?  Feed me charged particles at just the right angle and before they vanish forever I'll spin them up until they emit x rays like a pulsar.
> >[image: ![enter image description here]

I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.

> Some say I put an end to time itself since I red shift anything you do into the 0 Hz range.

Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

> Since finding my end would mean finding your end.

Comment: Another awesome answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> Electricity

People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.

> Electrons move on from atom to atom when a potential difference (voltage) is present, at least in metals (I'm  not an expert)

I've had an impact on many products and artists.

> *Electrical* products (technology) and artists (using modern tools on computers) which replaced older primitive equivalents

It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.

> Electricity itself (i.e stored charge, say) is invisible, as well as a lot of its components; under load, for example, producing heat which is invisible

I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.

> Electricity is regarded as essential for basic wellbeing in modern times (lighting, heating, etc.)

Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

> Development of more efficient sources of transportation and storage, sustainable production, and so on

Comment: Like the voltage part. Nice try.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be:

> A rainbow.

People say unity is beautiful, I dare to disagree.

> A rainbow is light that is broken into bands.  It is beautiful but not unified.

I've had an impact on many products and artists.

> "Somewhere Over the Rainbow", "Taste the rainbow", etc. show products
>  and artists inspired by a rainbow.

It upsets me that some human beings cannot see me some of my components.

> Colorblind people cannot see some of the colors of a rainbow.

I mark the end of difficult and tenacious times.

> The rainbow was a symbol to Noah that the Earth would not be flooded
>  again.

Yet people want to find my end, I always wonder why.

> People want to find the pot of gold at the end of the rainbow.

Comment: Typically with a riddle you should go line by line explaining why the answer you found is the correct one. Also this answer was already posted 3 hours prior to your own post. Please be sure to look at other answers before posting.

Comment: It's really a shame that the formatting is not proper for the answer is awesome otherwise.